# unable to fetch the exact information from a xml file.getting confusions

Tags: android, xml

I'm doing Android programming.

1) I looking to fetch the data from this xml file.[google weather xml api](http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=hyderabad)

now I am able to fetch the information for it normally. but when ever I am trying to show the data of the day-of-week it is giving me an the last weak date that is Tue (Tuesday).

2) in the main.xml file I have a textview and and a button called next. I am showing the Tue value from the google xml api in the oncreate method. what I am looking is on clicking the next button who can I get the weak first day.

in my first question I am getting the last value of the week and I want Saturday to be shown and on pressing the next button it should show me Sunday. I am getting Tue value in the textview but not the Saturday. Why is it happening?

in the mainactivity I am calling the textview to set the xml fetched data as

```
String question = doingWork.getquestion();
showQuestion.setText(question);
```

after that in the handlingxml class I have the code something like this

```
    public String getquestion(){
        return info.dataToquestion();
    }
```

and in the stratelement method

```
        if (localName.equals("date_of_week")){
            String question = attributes.getValue("data");
            info.setquestion(question);
        }
```

and finally in the xmldatacollected class

```
public void setquestion(String q){
        question = q;
    }
public String dataToquestion(){
        return ""+question;
    }
```

Comment: i have edited the question.plz look into it now

Comment: I can't see the node 'question_data' in the XMl you linked?

Comment: well i am extremly sorry sir, i have edited it again .plz rply me soon

Answer (score 0):

Issue is due to I think, You are repeating this in a loop, and last value in xml for day_of_week is Tue, so you need to have some array to store the list.

Like ArrayList list=new ArrayList();

and in

```
if (localName.equals("date_of_week")){
            Records info=new Record();
            String question = attributes.getValue("data");
            info.setquestion(question);
            list.add(info);
        }
```

to get first day just use=> list.get(0);
to get last day=> list.get(list.size()-1);